# error: name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build my first ATL DLL project, in which I'm using ADODB. The issue here is that I'm getting each ADODB class underlined

```
ADODB::_ConnectionPtr spADOConnection;
```

when I pass the mouse over on `ADODB::_ConnectionPtr` I get `name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name` `spADOConnection` I get `expected a ';'`. What's the mean of this, please? How do I to fix it please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: looks like C++ doesn't know that ADODB is a class or namespace, is everything correctly included/linked in your project? Are you getting any external symbol errors during compilation?

Comment: @Gmercer015, I've correctly included `msado60.dll`, yes I'm getting an external symbol on `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long __stdcall CTProcessus::Init(class ATL::CStringT > >,wchar_t *,wchar_t *,wchar_t *)"`

Comment: You don't include DLLs, you include header files.

Comment: @Luciekulza as juanchopanza said, your .dll would be placed in the same directory as your executable. It's not something you would include from the properties page

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The compiler is unable to locate the declaration of `ADODB`. Make sure you include the relevant header in the translation unit where the compiler complains.

Comment: The compiler has got nothing to do with DLLs which come at a much later stage. This is more at the code generation phase where the compiler needs to verify the type you're trying to use. There should be a header where the type `ADODB` is introduced. Make sure it's included in the source file you're trying to compile.